# An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode. The property "path" says to be duplicated

Tags: angular, angular-routing

```
import { CustomerComponenet } from "src/CustomerApp/CustomerApp.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./LoginApp.component";

export const CustomerRoutes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LoginComponent,
  path: 'Customer',
  component: CustomerComponenet,
  path: 'Login',
  component: LoginComponent
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Routes expecting array of paths, it needs to be like this, you forgot to separate path as object

```
import { CustomerComponenet } from "src/CustomerApp/CustomerApp.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./LoginApp.component";

export const CustomerRoutes = [{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Customer',
    component: CustomerComponenet
  },
  {
    path: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
]
```